# Inheriting std::vector::iterator for custom class?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, iterator

I am implementing a custom class that contains an STL `std::vector` as central data member.
Now, I would like this class to provide an iterator, which merely needs to iterate through this vector and also works with C++11 range based iteration.
It is very tempting to just somehow inherit the iterator from `std::vector::iterator` as it is supposed to do exactly the same job. Is this possible or do I need to implement a completely custom iterator?

```
class Custom {
private:
  std::vector<double> _data;
public:
  class iterator {
    // Want this to provide an interface to iterate through _data
    // ...
  };
  // ...
};

Custom C;
// Populate C with data ...
for (const auto& item : C) {
  // This should print the elements within _data.
  std::cout << item << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why "inherit from"? Why not simply typedef? As in `class Custom { using iterator = std::vector<double>::iterator; };` For the range loop to work, you would still need to implement `begin()` and `end()`, likely by forwarding to `_data.begin()` and `_data.end()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to inherit from the iterator itself. You can just provide interfaces for the iterators used by the `std::vector<double>`.

Here is a quick snippet:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Custom {
private:
  std::vector<double> _data;
public:
  explicit Custom(std::initializer_list<double> init) : _data(init) {}

  using iterator = std::vector<double>::iterator;
  using const_iterator = std::vector<double>::const_iterator;

  iterator begin()
  {
    return _data.begin();
  } 

  iterator end()
  {
    return _data.end();
  } 

  const_iterator cbegin() const
  {
    return _data.cbegin();
  } 

  const_iterator cend() const
  {
    return _data.cend();
  } 
};

int main()
{
  Custom C({ 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0 });
  for (const auto &item : C)
  {
    std::cout << item << "\n";
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this mostly worked for me. For some reason I had to add overloaded `const_iterator begin() const { return _data.cbegin(); }` and the corresponding `end()` since the range-based for loop would not otherwise automatically switch to the `cbegin()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can make public proxy-functions for

- `vector<T>::begin()`
- `vector<T>::end()`
- `vector<T>::cbegin()`
- `vector<T>::cend()`
- and other vector member functions which create iterators

And iterate over your object like that:

```
Custom custom;

// here insert any data

for(auto it = custom.cbegin(); it != custom.cend(); ++it){
    cout << *it;
}
```

Also, it will work for range-based for:

```
for(const auto &val : custom){
     cout << val;
}
```