# typedef a vector and boost::numeric::ublas::vector of fixed size

Tags: c++, vector, boost, typedef, boost-ublas

I mean to `typedef` a name for a vector / boost vector with fixed size, and then for corresponding iterators.
What I *could* do is (see below)

```
typedef std::array<double, 3> point_3d_array;
typedef point_3d_array::iterator point_3d_iterator;
typedef point_3d_array::const_iterator point_3d_const_iterator;
```

The idea is to use later in my code something like

```
point_3d_array p;
for ( point_3d_const_iterator it = p.begin() ; it != p.end() ; it++ ) {
   my code
}
```

**Question 1:** Is this possible with

1. `std::vector<double>`
2. `boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>`?

If it is not possible:

1. **Question 2:** What is an alternative implementation? (other than that below).
2. **Question 3:** How would I `typedef` the iterators?

As of now, since I couldn't find a way to do it, I defined my own class (see below).
But this carries the burden of (at least) having to redefine my own `begin`, `end` and iterators (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405596/inheriting-stdvectoriterator-for-custom-class)). I mean to avoid this.

**Question 4:**
I put together two alternative lines in the definition of `operator+=` (see below).
One of them is not working. What is the problem?

```
typedef std::array<double, 3> point_3d_array;
typedef point_3d_array::iterator point_3d_iterator;
typedef point_3d_array::const_iterator point_3d_const_iterator;

class point_3d {
public:
    /*
     * Default constructor
     */
    point_3d() : _point_3d({ 0, 0, 0 }) { };
    /*
     * Initialization constructor
     * Is copy constructor automatically generated?
     */
    point_3d(const double x1, const double x2, const double x3) : _point_3d({x1, x2, x3}) {};

    /*
     * Iterator members
     */
    point_3d_iterator begin() { return _point_3d.begin(); }
    point_3d_iterator end() { return _point_3d.end(); }
    point_3d_const_iterator begin() const { return _point_3d.begin(); }
    point_3d_const_iterator end() const { return _point_3d.end(); }
    /*
     * Array subscript operators
     */
    double & operator[](size_t i) {
        return this->_point_3d[ i ];
    }
    const double & operator[](size_t i) const {
        return this->_point_3d[ i ];
    }

    /*
     * Basic operation members
     */
    point_3d & operator+=(const point_3d &rhs) {
        for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < this->_point_3d.size() ; i++ ) {
            //this[ i ] += rhs[ i ];  // Why are Array subscript operators not working in the lhs?
            this->_point_3d[ i ] += rhs[ i ];
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    point_3d_array _point_3d;
};
```

Comment: typedef the iterators do not need a fixed size.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `std::vector` nor (at the time of writing) `boost::numeric::ublas::vector` are *designed* to be a fixed size. There's no template parameter that specifies the size of the container.

So no, a fixed sized `typedef` makes no sense for these containers.

If you want to constrain the size of a `std::vector`, then one approach would be to write your own template class with a `std::vector` to model the payload.

Comment: Please see updated OP.
I infer (as I first thought) that the answer to Q1 is "no".
The only option would be a new class, as I did (Why a template class?), so the answer to Q2 would be "there is no other alternative".
And yet I have to solve Q4.

Answer (score 2):

boost::numeric::ublas has a fixed size storage container and a fixed size vector.
I am not sure if you have to use`typedef` for iterator types and vector types.
Here is a small example how to use both types and mix them even with `std::array` or `std::vector`.

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>

using namespace boost::numeric;
using value_t = float;

int main () {
    constexpr auto N = 5ul;
    auto a = ublas::bounded_array<value_t,N>{N};
    auto b = ublas::fixed_vector<value_t,N>{};
    auto c = std::array<value_t,N>{};

    auto print = [](auto n, auto v){
        std::cout << n << "= "; 
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<value_t>(std::cout, " ")); 
        std::cout << std::endl;
    };

    std::iota(a.begin(), a.end(), value_t(1));
    std::iota(b.begin(), b.end(), value_t(1));
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), c.begin(), [](auto const& aa, auto const& bb){return aa+bb;});

    auto d = 2*b + b;

    print("a",a);
    print("b",b);
    print("c",c);
    print("d",d);
    return 0;
}
```